# Conditionally remove let-binding in lisp macro

Tags: emacs, lisp-macros

How can I conditionally remove a let-binding in a `defun` created in a lisp macro?  Here, I want to remove the first let-bound variable from the resulting function, but am running into a problem where I have a `nil` that sticks around in the let bindings, causing an error.

For example, the resulting function uses `let` or `let*` and should remove the first variable assignment depending on `arg`.  But the way I have it written the problem comes from replacing `var1` with `nil`.  I'm not sure how to get rid of the nil.

```
(cl-defmacro mac (cmd &optional arg)
  (let ((fn (intern (concat "fn-" cmd))))
    `(defun ,fn ()
       (interactive)
       (,(if arg 'let* 'let)
        (cons
         ,(when arg
            '(var1 1))
         (var2 (if (bound-and-true-p var1) (+ var1 1) 1)))
        (message "%s" var2)))))

(mac "fun")    ; Attempt to set constant: nil
(mac "fun2" t) ; no problem
;; (symbol-function 'fn-fun)
;; (symbol-function 'fn-fun2)
;; (fn-fun)
;; (fn-fun2)
```

Comment: The easiest workaround is probably to use `,@(when arg '((var1 1)))`. Is that `cons` supposed to be a function call? It's quoted, so right now you're also defining a variable named `cons`. It looks unnecessary to me.

Comment: `macroexpand` is your friend. Use it to find out just what your macro calls expand to. In this case it tells you that the relevant part expands to `(let (cons nil (var2 ...))...), which binds a variable named `cons` and tries to bind one named `nil`.

Comment: Your question is not a question about Emacs Lisp, per se. It's a question about Lisp macros. I added tag `lisp-macros`, because on StackOverflow the tag `macros` doesn't really mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest workaround is probably to use `,@(when arg '((var1 1)))`. `,@` is used to splice a list into the position. Since `WHEN` returns `NIL` if the condition fails, and `NIL` is the same as an empty list, the splice effectively ignores it. When the condition succeeds `((var1 1))` is returned, and `(var1 1)` is unwrapped by the splice.